# Copy values from a column only if they contain a word from another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, iwork-numbers

I have two columns:

1. The first one contains words (column "A" on the screenshot).
2. The second column contains text values (column "C" on the screenshot).

I'd like to copy the words from the second column to another column, only if a cell contains the word from the first column.

here is a screenshot to illustrate the problem:
[image]

I.e., the word in the `img` tag should correspond the word in the column "A". Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: Are you considering whole text in Column A or partial Text !! Better edit sample data and add value in C to match with Row in Col A,, and define what to Copy,, whole or partial text !!

Comment: @RajeshS I need to copy the whole value in a cell from the column “C” (I.e., the whole img tag). But I copy it only if it contains the word from the column “A”.

Comment: you mean Word is partial match,,better edit sample data since it's confusing a bit !!

Comment: @RajeshS yes, partial match. I can’t edit it because the spreadsheet contains hundreds of words. And the data needs to stay like that.

Comment: And what you are suppose to copy value from Col C or another one!

Comment: @RajeshS yes. I need to copy the value from the Col “C” — the whole img tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92100/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-anton-k).